# Unsupervised outlier detection using autoencoders (python) with pyod

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, outliers

PyOD: python unsupervised outlier detection with auto encoders

I found this tutorial online that does outlier detection (with pyod in python) .

https://towardsdatascience.com/anomaly-detection-with-pyod-b523fc47db9

However, the tutorial does not show how to trace the outlier scores back to the original data - how can I actually determine which observations were the outliers? I have attached the code below.

Thanks!

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.models.auto_encoder import AutoEncoder
from pyod.utils.data import generate_data

contamination = 0.1  # percentage of outliers
n_train = 500  # number of training points
n_test = 500  # number of testing points
n_features = 25 # Number of features

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = generate_data(
    n_train=n_train, n_test=n_test,
    n_features= n_features, 
    contamination=contamination,random_state=1234)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_train = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_train)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
X_test = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X_test)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(X_test)


clf1 = AutoEncoder(hidden_neurons =[25, 2, 2, 25])
clf1.fit(X_train)

# Get the outlier scores for the train data
y_train_scores = clf1.decision_scores_  

# Predict the anomaly scores
y_test_scores = clf1.decision_function(X_test)  # outlier scores
y_test_scores = pd.Series(y_test_scores)

# Plot it!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(y_test_scores, bins='auto')  
plt.title("Histogram for Model Clf1 Anomaly Scores")
plt.show()

df_test = X_test.copy()
df_test['score'] = y_test_scores
df_test['cluster'] = np.where(df_test['score']<4, 0, 1)
df_test['cluster'].value_counts()

df_test.groupby('cluster').mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late since this question was asked 5 months ago from now.

Continuing from your code snippet provided, I see that you have the 'score' column which you can make use of. You can do something like this.

I used seaborn to plot the points.

```
import seaborn as sns

normal = df_test['score'] < 4  # returns a mask where normal = True
anomalous = df_test['score'] >= 4
sns.scatterplot(data=df_test[normal])
sns.scatterplot(data=df_test[anomalous])
plt.legend(['normal', 'anomalous'])
plt.title('Normal vs Anomalous Points')
plt.xlabel('some x label')
plt.ylabel('some y label')
```